# How to prevent reloading of iframe in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe

There is an api from which I get html document contents, currently I am taking data in chunks and setting to state and there is iframe whose "srcDoc" attribute is taking that value from state. What I want to do is prevent reloading of iframe because each time "srcDoc" is set iframe scroll is taken to top and it reloads.
Here's code :

```js
 const stream = new Promise(() => {
      axios({
        url: `http://54.90.50.223/api/mainapi/Documents/GetHTML`,
        method: "GET",
        onDownloadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
          const dataChunk = progressEvent.currentTarget.response;
          console.log(dataChunk);
          str += dataChunk;
          this.setState({ srcDoc: str });
        },
      }).then(({ data }) => Promise.resolve(data));
    });
```